# React / Javascript - Output HTML tag in string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Apologies if this is a simple question, I'm fairly new to vanilla JS and React.

Is it possible to output simple HTML tags (Ie; `<strong>`) in a React / JS string?

This is what I'm working with currently;

```
renderArtistFeatures() {
    const createFeatures = [
        {
            feature: 'free',
            Icon: FreeIcon,
            title: 'Main title',
            copy: 'Some sample text with a <strong>HTML tag</strong>'
        }
    ].map(({ feature, Icon, title, copy }, i) => {
        const klass = `create-feature create-feature--${feature} column small-24 medium-8`;

        return (
            <div key={i} className={klass}>
                <div className="create-feature__inner">
                    <div className="create-feature__icon create-feature__icon--free">
                        <Icon />
                    </div>
                    <div className="create-feature__content">
                        <h2 className="create-feature__title">{title}</h2>
                        <p>{copy}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    });
    return (
       // My other code is output here
    );
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to output some bold text using HTML tags, but obviously it isn't working.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

JSX is compiled to javascript before running in browser with babel.js .
If you get generated code from http://babeljs.io : Clearly "copy is just an string"

```
 'use strict';

function renderArtistFeatures() {
    var createFeatures = [{
        feature: 'free',
        Icon: FreeIcon,
        title: 'Main title',
        copy: 'Some sample text with a <strong>HTML tag</strong>'
    }].map(function (_ref, i) {
        var feature = _ref.feature,
            Icon = _ref.Icon,
            title = _ref.title,
            copy = _ref.copy;

        var klass = 'create-feature create-feature--' + feature + ' column small-24 medium-8';

        return React.createElement(
            'div',
            { key: i, className: klass },
            React.createElement(
                'div',
                { className: 'create-feature__inner' },
                React.createElement(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'create-feature__icon create-feature__icon--free' },
                    React.createElement(Icon, null)
                ),
                React.createElement(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'create-feature__content' },
                    React.createElement(
                        'h2',
                        { className: 'create-feature__title' },
                        title
                    ),
                    React.createElement(
                        'p',
                        null,
                        copy
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    });
}

renderArtistFeatures();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this before return:

```
const copyText = document.createElement("span");
copy.innerHTML = copy;
```

and then use this `copyText` inside return.